# Checking for imports order with pylama

Tags: python, isort, pylama

I use [autoflake](https://github.com/myint/autoflake) to automatically remove unused imports and variables from my code locally and [pylama](https://github.com/klen/pylama) on Jenkins CI to check the code for multiple things, including unused imports and imported variables (W0611).

Now I would like to introduce [isort](https://github.com/timothycrosley/isort) to the project to sort imports.

Is there a way for pylama to check if imports are properly sorted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found isort has already pylama plugin. It's implemented in [isort repository](https://github.com/timothycrosley/isort/blob/develop/isort/pylama_isort.py) and mentioned in pylama help output:

```
pylama -h
  ...
  --linters LINTERS, -l LINTERS
                        Select linters. (comma-separated). Choices are mccabe,
                        pep257,pydocstyle,pep8,pycodestyle,pyflakes,isort.
```

It's not enabled by default so you need to configure pylama explicitly

```
pylama --linters isort file_to_test
```

or in `pylama.ini` configuration file

```
[pylama]
linters = isort
```

([Default linters](https://github.com/klen/pylama/blob/develop/pylama/config.py#L15) are pycodestyle, pyflakes, mccabe).

In contrast to `check -c` it doesn't provide information which lines are incorrectly imported. If something is wrong it always shows same error message:

```
file_to_test.py:0: [I] Incorrectly sorted imports. [isort]
```